# Copycating static variables (file scope) behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, static-variables

By static, I mean, that the object (variable) would not change. Say I have a python module named `my_static_vars`, and it contains `a`, whose starting value is `10` (integer).

I have one function in that module:

```
def prntandinc(): #print and increase
     print a
     a += 1
```

When I import the module from another program I want it to output `11`. But I wouldn't be asking this if there weren't any special restrictions.

I cannot save it in a file, not only that the access would be a lot slower, the data I need to be static is pretty large in size, and it'll have to load it every time.

I thought of having my module run in a permanent loop (well, until it is told otherwise) and listen to interprocess comunication (meaning I wouldn't import it, just have it receive a request from the 'importing' program and send the necessary response). Now, in my case, that would probably suffice - as all that that module does is generate a random serial number and make sure it does not appear in the `used_serials` (which should act static for this to be possible) list (the reason I do not want to use files is because I generate large amount of serial numbers in quite a small amount of time) - but I wondered if there's a less complex solution.

Is there any not-too-complex way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a database will do. Just `import sqlite3`.

Creating a table (will save it in the current directory as `serials.db`):

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('serials.db') #Will create a new table as it doesn't exist right now
cur = conn.cursor() #We will use this to execute commands
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE serials_tb (serial text)''') #for more than one column add a comma, as in a tuple, and write '[COL_NAME] [COL_TYPE]' without the apostrophes. You might want (as I suppose you only want a serial to be used once) to define it as a primary key
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Adding a serial:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('serials.db') #Will connect to the existing database
cur = conn.cursor() 
data = ('MY_SERIAL',) #a tuple
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO serials_tb VALUES (?)''', data)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Selecting a serial (seeing if it exists already):

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('serials.db') #Will connect to the existing database
cur = conn.cursor()
data = ('MY_SERIAL',)
qry = cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM serials_tb WHERE serial=?''', data)
#You can iterate over it and get a tuple of each row ('for row in qry:')
#But to check if a col exists, in your case, you can do so:
if len(qry.fetchall()) != 0:
    #The serial is used
else:
    #The serial isn't used
```

NOTE: You, obviously, don't need to import `sqlite3` every time (only in each file, but not every time you execute a command, nor you need to connect or close the connection every execution of a command. Commit the changes when you need to, connect at the beginning and close the connection at the end.
For more info, you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of it myself. Thank you so much, just what I need